# mysql query error simple

Tags: php, mysql

can you tell me whats going wong here ?:)

```
        <?php
            if (isset($_POST['opretbruger'])){

            $brugernavn = $_POST["brugernavn"];
            $brugertype = $_POST ["brugertype"];
            $fornavn = $_POST["fornavn"];
            $efternavn = $_POST["efternavn"];
            $tlf = $_POST["tlf"];
            $email = $_POST["email"];
            $password = $_POST["password"];

            echo $brugernavn;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $fornavn;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $efternavn;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $tlf;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $email;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $password;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $brugertype;

             mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (
                                                                `id` ,
                                                                `username` ,
                                                                `password` ,
                                                                `first_name` ,
                                                                `last_name` ,
                                                                `tlf` ,
                                                                `email` ,
                                                                `useres_types`
                                                                )
                                                                VALUES (NULL, '$brugernavn', '$password', '$fornavn', '$efternavn', '$tlf', '$email', '$password'))") or die(mysql_error());

            echo $brugernavn, $fornavn, $efternavn, $tlf, $email, $password, $brugertype;

            }
        ?>

        <form name="opretbruger" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
            <table >
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Brugernavn:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="brugernavn">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Bruger type:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="brugertype">
                            <option value="1">Bruger</option>
                            <option value="3">Admin</option>
                        </select> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Fornavn:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="fornavn">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Efternavn:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="efternavn">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Tlf.:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="tlf">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Email:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="email" type="email">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        password:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="password" type="password">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Opret bruger" name="opretbruger">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>   
        </form>
```

fail:

> Warning: mysql_query(): No such file or directory in ** on line 61
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established
>   in ** on line 61 No such file or directory

Comment: Where is your connection?

Comment: in my header i include config.php ->

Comment: $servername = "**";
$username1 = "**";
$password = "**";
$database = "**";

// Create connection
$conn =   mysqli_connect($servername, $username1, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
?>

Comment: you can't mix mysqli and mysql commands. Use `mysqli_query( $conn, $query )`

Comment: or, i found a fail i use mysql in connect and mysqli in slecet.

Comment: bot now then give me this fail Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in ** on line 61

Comment: @KathrineIversen see [mysqli_queri doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) (or my previous comment...)

Answer (score -1):

Create database connection using `mysql_connect()` function.